# Translating a base Object into an Object that extends the base Object

Tags: java

I have an auto-generated class with a non-unique name. Due to being unable to alter this class or the file that generated the class I placed it into its own package. This resulted in needing to type the whole package anytime I need to declare or caste this object.

My solution to this was to create a subclass as follows

```
public UniqueName extends BaseClass
{
   // This class is empty and intended to be used as an alias. 
}
```

Unfortunately I have run into another issue where serialization and deserialization can only be done on the base class.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to transform that base class into the alias class that extends it? I have tried casting the base class into the alias class but I receive several errors from eclipse.

Comment: You can always use a factory; "package ugliness" would then only be in a single place.

Comment: What do you mean by a factory?

Comment: @fge Alternatively, put the class in the same package as the code referencing it, and use the fully-qualified names for the other classes that share the same base name, if they happen to have shorter fully-qualified names.

Comment: @JME http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern So you'd end up using a call similar to `MyClass.getInstanceOfNonUniqueClass().doSomething()`. Or you could make a wrapper class whose instances hold instances of the other class and then you'd do `instanceofWrapperClass.getInnerObject()` or however you want to name things. (The first version might be more useful for one-time objects while the latter could be better for more persistent ones, but I don't have quite enough experience to say if that's definitely the case.)

Comment: I have been reading through the Wiki and several stack overflow threads, as well as other documentation found through google. I do not understand how creating a factory method will help me in this situation, it seems as if I am completely reconstructing the original class inside the subclass, which seems to defeat the purpose of the subclass entirely.

Comment: They mean so create the factory class... then from that you call one of two methods - one that returns the first Unique version, another returns the second Unique version in a different package. So you only specify the package names within the factory class. To get the second unique method for example you write: SecondVersion secondVersion = UniqueFactory.getSecondVersion();

Comment: I do not believe the a Factory will work for me in this instance. I do not want to return an instance of the base class. I would like to transform the base class into the alias class, where I can call the methods on the alias class directly. The classes are returned to third party applications so returning an instance of the base class does not solve the problem of the third party user having to declare the entire package himself

Comment: Alright you can do that by extending it as you've done above. But you said you had some serialize issues. If the base class is serializable that should make the extended classes serializable too.

Comment: The serialization and deserialization is done by JibX off a a JibX binding, it doesn't use java serializable. I have tried using JAXB as an alternative but I still run into the same issue.

Comment: What about just having a non extended class with its own methods and holding a UniqueName field within it - then you create any methods to access that object from outside the external class. You can then return a UniqueName object if needed to the serializer and accept one from the deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that, for some reason BaseClass is unmodifiable and you want to end up with a more "useful" version of BaseClass.

Instead of extending BaseClass, delegate to it on the UniqueName:

```
public BaseClass{
    public void usefulMethod() { ... }

    public void lessUsefulMethod() { ... }
}

public UniqueName 
{
    private BaseClass baseClass;

    public UniqueName(BaseClass baseClass){ this.baseClass = baseClass; } 

    public void usefulMethod() { return baseClass.usefulMethod(); }

    public void moreUsefulMethod(){
       ...
       baseClass.lessUsefulMethod();
       ... 
    }
}
```

Instead of type-casting from BaseClass to UniqueName, you create an instance of UniqueName using the constructor taking BaseClass as a parameter.

If you need to keep "is-a" relationship of UniqueName with the BaseClass, you may do it so. But do not forget to override each method and delegate it to the baseClass instance.

P.S.: If you are having problems with the object replacements in the serialization/deserialization, ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream classes have replaceObject and resolveObject methods, which allows us to replace the types of objects in the serialization.